# navigation is not working in autolink all

Tags: android

i am using the autolink to navigate the link. but it is not working. when extends activity it is working but incase of fragment activity it is not working. pls help me anyone....thanks in advance

here is my code,

xml -

```
<TextView
                        android:id="@+id/chat_compact_message"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:text="@string/message" />
```

java code -

```
SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(text));

                Log.i("spprint::::::::::::", sp.toString());

                application.emotifySpannable(sp);

                holder.message.setText(sp);

                Linkify.addLinks(holder.message, Linkify.ALL);

                  if (holder.message != null) {
                      holder.message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                 }
```

Comment: have you think it is depends upon Activity or Fragment ?

Comment: when i do it independently as a new project it is working. but when i exclude with this existing code there the problem is coming

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add the string to set the text like

```
&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">Google&lt;/a>
```

and try